# How to hide overlay pressing Back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Firstly: I ma very new in jQuery and web front-end.

Problem:
I have a [test site](http://past.is/AIhq)

Steps to see the problem:

1. Click on [UploadTest]
2. Click on any pic in gallery to see an overlay
3. Click on browser's Back button

Now I see main page with the overlay.
Question is how to hide overlay when I leave the gallery page by Back button?

Sometime othe overlay is hidden but when I go on gallery page again it is visible.

How to hide it automatically?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:** Sorry, I can not post sources because I do not know where is problem. Please if you have a minute look inside sources in browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
        $(window).on('popstate', function () {
            $("#galleryOverlay").css('display', 'none')
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: what about $("#galleryOverlay").hide()

Comment: @Borza Adrian You have saved lot of my time. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sure, the engine required to wait some time before make a check. Thanks a lot again.