# Javascript hide overlay using back button not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Using Wordpress CMS

I have three overlays which are triggered via image. They have close buttons, but client wishes these to close via browser back button as well (some of you may disagree with this as poor UX I know). I can see the argument for it on mobile browsers.

I have the following code

```
<script>
    jQuery(function($) {
        if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
            $(window).on('popstate', function () {
                 $(".overlay-container").css('display', 'none')
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Not functioning at all - what am I missing?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This may help.

```
window.onhashchange = function () {
        $(".overlay-container").fadeIn(500);
        $('body')
      .css('overflow', 'hidden');
    }
```

Comment: @James I think this is the similar issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23760625/how-to-hide-overlay-pressing-back-button

Comment: sure is - that implementation won't work either. Stuck.